# how to match dir path in win7 using regular expression

Tags: regex

I need to match dir path ..

```
str=C:\somedir1\somedir2 tmp\somedir5  tt\..
```

str may or may not contain one or more spaces in the begining.
I tried

```
findstr /r "^ *[ABCD]:\+..".
```

Does not seems to work ..

Thanks

Comment: try `findstr /r "^ *[ABCD]:\\.+\.\.$"`

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Take a look at [formatting](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) help page. It would be easier to read your question.

Answer (score 0):

echo C:\Users\desk\Desktop\eca 05 | findstr  /r "^ *[ABCD]:\.+..$" is ok

echo asasC:\Users\desk\Desktop\eca 05 | findstr  /r "^ *[ABCD]:\.+..$"

returns --

asasC:\Users\desk\Desktop\eca 05 | findstr  /r "^ *[ABCD]:\.+..$"... that is wrong.